# UITableView inside UIViewController using Parse PFQueryTableViewController

Tags: ios, uitableview, storyboard, parse-platform

I need to create a `UIViewController` which has a `UITableView` inside it. I found some similar questions on here but I want to use a separate class a my data source and delegate, a class that will subclass `PFQueryTableViewController` from Parse SDK.

So in my storyboard I have one `UIViewController` with one `UITableView` on it.

I also have a class called `ArticleTableViewController` (inherits from `PFQueryTableViewController`). I would like this class to be the delegate and the datasource for my table view, but I don´t know how to connect them correctly.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I tried to do something like this, i've got the answer: you can't use the *PFQuaryTableViewController* as a subclass of a *UIViewController*.

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23387999/tableviewcontroller-or-view-controller-with-table-view-for-parse-api-query) my original question with the answer and some useful suggestions.